# What manufacturers produce displays with no air holes?

Tags: monitors, displays

Most budget computer displays (Under $200) on the market have ventilation holes on the back. Its hard to find a budget display with no ventilation holes, like smartphones are. Are there any monitors like this, or brands that have similar designs?

Comment: What do you understand as "Budget"? Under €100? Under €200? Please add a budget

Comment: Within 200 bucks

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want ventilation?

Comment: @Alphy13 it doesn't look good, dust gets in, harder to wipe.

Answer (score 2):

Monitors, like all electronics, produce heat. The cheapest way to get rid of this heat is to provide a path for the hot air to rise and cool air to flow in and across the device.

The only monitors I have seen without ventilation are portable ones [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097MZGZ2Y). It is currently $170 when you apply the coupon. If you search "portable monitor" you will find plenty more like this.

I would highly recommend using separate speakers. You are not likely to get anything worth listening to out of a "budget" monitor. External speakers are both higher quality, and cheaper.